# Battery behaving weirdly in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, power-management, shutdown, lenovo, battery

I asked this question 2-3 times before but didn't get any answer. My laptop is Lenovo 15ay542-tu, I switched to ubuntu20.04 2 months ago.

1. After reaching 80% my laptops switches from charging state to discharging state and after some time(1 minute) again to charging state and this cycle continues until it reaches 100%.
2. My laptop reaches 100% (wow!) but as soon as I remove my plug it goes down to 93%.
3. My laptop shutdowns when the battery reaches around 45% and after that, if I try to start it again it opens (goes where I see Lenovo written on the screen) and again shutdowns.

Is this any update problem, because I saw similar questions with `battery` tag in recent days, which means this same problem is happening to my users at the same time.

I would like to specify that I wakeup a morning and I noticed these things happening, If it is battery fault then this should not be happening instantly.

I have tried `power-calibrate  -R -r 20 -d 5 -s 21 -n 0 -p` but no improvement.